# INSERT TRIGGER problems: "Key column information is insufficient or incorrect. Too many rows were affected by update."

Tags: sql-server-2008, ms-access, triggers

I am having some problems with my TRIGGER:

```
CREATE TRIGGER "tblSettingTable_INSERT"
ON dbo.tblSettingTable
FOR INSERT
    AS

INSERT INTO dbo.tblSettingReportParameter (tableName, columnName, columnCaption)
SELECT   tableName = CAST(OBJECT_NAME(c.object_id) AS varchar(100)),
            columnName = CAST(c.name AS varchar(100)),
            columnCaption = CAST(ex.value AS varchar(100))
FROM        sys.columns c
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.extended_properties ex
            ON ex.major_id = c.object_id 
            AND ex.minor_id = c.column_id  
            AND ex.name = 'MS_Caption'
INNER JOIN  inserted ON OBJECT_NAME(c.object_id) = inserted.tableName
WHERE      OBJECTPROPERTY(c.object_id, 'IsMsShipped')=0  
         AND OBJECT_NAME(c.object_id) = inserted.tableName
```

I am trying the get some column properties from a table and INSERT it into `dbo.tblSettingReportParameter` but I get this thrown at my face: *"Key column information is insufficient or incorrect. Too many rows were affected by update."*

What am I doing wrong? Using MS-SQL 2008 RS.

Thanks,

Stefan

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Should be fixed if you add [`SET NOCOUNT ON`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1483732/set-nocount-on-usage) to the trigger.

The `xx rows returned` is confusing Access (which I assume issues the INSERT to SQL Server of course based on the tags for the question)