# No resultset if the store procedures does an update before the select on MSSQL server 2005

Tags: java, sql-server, stored-procedures, jdbc

Does any one have any idea why I wont get a resultset if I do an update before the select in a store procedure. Im running MSSQL server 2005 and the latest Microsoft JDBC driver.

Relevant java code:

```
CallableStatement cstmt = con.prepareCall("{call dbo.sp_groups_select}");
if (cstmt.execute()) {
    while (cstmt.getResultSet().next())
```

Does not get a resultset if the store procedure looks like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_groups_select] AS
update Computers set ComputerName='Foo'  where ComputerName='bar';
select * from Computers;
```

But if it looks like this I do get a resultset

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_groups_select] AS
select * from Computers;
update Computers set ComputerName='Foo'  where ComputerName='bar';
```

Comment: Have you run it on the database directly?  (Trying to see if this is a SQL-Server issue or Java)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Probably because you need `SET NOCOUNT ON`

The `(x rows affected)` equivalent is processed as a resultset in the client, which bollixes `cstmt.getResultSet().next()`

Shameless plug of my question about [SET NOCOUNT ON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1483732/set-nocount-on-usage)

Comment: Ahh that was it, now it works :) I was troubleshooting that one for a few hours and then it was solved in an hour here..  Got to love stackoverflow

Comment: @gbn I'd buy you a drink. been banging my bonky head for the last four hours with Mr. DBA trying to fix this