# Can't edit NEW records in Access 2003 with ODBC connection to SQL 2005 tables

Tags: sql-server-2005

I am having problems editing any NEW records added to an existing SQL database.  We purchased a software program that is based in MS SQL 2005.  The front end of the software doesn't allow us to create our own queries or reports (the company wants $250 for each one).  So, I created an Access 2003 database and linked via ODBC connection all the tables in the SQL database.  I've been running queries and reports to my heart's content and so far so good.  The problem is that if I go into one of the linked tables and try to edit any record that has been added since we purchased the software I get an error that says "The record has been changed by another user since you started editing it..."  We had over 100,000 records converted into the new software and I can edit any of those records just fine.  I read through some of the other suggestions and the only one that seemed to apply was adding the TimeStamp field.  I did, relinked the table, didn't change anything.  All the other suggestions had to do with permissions.  Since I can edit other records in the same table I assume this to not be the issue.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Anyway, check for a trigger on the table concerned.

If this updates the row you have just edited then it will change the timestamp (should actually be [rowversion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776.aspx)) and confuse MS Access.

If it doesn't update this row, then check the trigger has SET NOCOUNT ON specified. This will affect the return info that MS Access gets which [confuses it.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1483732/set-nocount-on-usage)