# SQL statement. need help understanding it

Tags: sql, database

I am findiing it hard to understand what this code is doing. Could someone please help me understand this code line by line so that I can understand what it is doing.

```
CREATE TRIGGER LowCredit ON Order
AFTER INSERT
AS

DECLARE @creditrating tinyint

SELECT @creditrating = v.CreditRating
FROM Customer c INNER JOIN inserted i
ON c.custID = i.custID

IF @creditrating = 5
BEGIN

    RAISERROR ('This customers''s credit rating
    is too low to accept new orders.’)

    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION

END
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is checking to see if the credit rating is a certain value, if its too low is raising an error and rolling back the transaction.

```
--Declare a trigger with name `LowCredit` on table `Order`, 
--run the trigger after 
CREATE TRIGGER LowCredit ON Order  
insert.
AFTER INSERT

AS
--start definition
--declare int
DECLARE @creditrating tinyint

--select from existing customer record the
-- inserted rows credit ranking (by custID)
-- inserted is the vt containing the changed rows
SELECT @creditrating = v.CreditRating
   FROM Customer c INNER JOIN inserted i
ON c.custID = i.custID
--if lower than 5 roll back
IF @creditrating = 5
BEGIN
--raise error to the session
RAISERROR ('This customers''s credit rating
is too low to accept new orders.’)
--roll back transaction
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION

END
```

Comment: -1 As per my issues in my answer. The code is wrong even if you are correct.

Comment: He didn't ask me to find a bug, he asked to explain the code.

Answer (score 1):

The ROLLBACK in the trigger will prevent the insert of the row in `Order` if the customer's credit rating is too low...

`inserted` is a virtual table containing the inserted row(s).

Answer (score 1):

The error is on line 7. Replace `v.` with `i.` or `c.`.

Answer (score 0):

`INSERTED` is a special table that contains a copy of new (or changed for UPDATE) rows in the `Order` table

This is used to look into the `Customer` table to find the credit rating.

If the credit rating is too low, an error is thrown

Some issues:

- it won't handle multiple row (eg many ORDERs in one go). The actual credit rating being checked will be a random row out of however many are inserted
- no TRY/CATCH block to give better error handling and stop the trigger being batch aborting
- missing [SET NOCOUNT ON](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1483732/27535) will break most clients at some point

Notes:

- the trigger is part of the INSERT statement scope and the associated transaction

Answer (score 0):

Its checking "CreditRating" of Customer whose order is being created if Rating is less then 5 and error will be raised and transaction will be Rollback. I hope coder has used Begin Transaction somewhere else other wise RollBack transaction without Begin will give error