# trigger not working

Tags: database, sql-server-2008, triggers

I wrote a trigger for whenever an update occurs in the table. But the trigger is not executing after update. The db used is SQLServer.

```
create trigger mytrigger on t_emp after update
as
begin
   select * from t_emp
end
```

Thanks

Comment: What do you expect the trigger to do? How do you know it is not executed?

Comment: @Alex Aza  :It should the retrieve the rows of the that particular table after update.

Comment: What should it do with rows when rows are retrieved?

Comment: @Alex Aza: if i am performing delete or update , its working. Can we use select query to display the updated row???

Comment: only with the OUTPUT clause, see my answer please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Triggers are used for further processing after UPDATEs or INSERTs etc, typically for history or audit tables, or for complex data integrity logic. Not for data retrieval. Triggers can break a lot of client code ([see this on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1483732/27535))

- To get the output of what you've just updated, use the [OUTPUT clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx).
- To get all rows from the table, use a second SELECT statement