# Usage of SET NOCOUNT ON

Tags: sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SET NOCOUNT ON usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1483732/set-nocount-on-usage)

Why do we use the below statement in Triggers and stored procedures?

`SET NOCOUNT ON`

Could any one explain me please? I have gone through the similar question posted before. But as I am new learning SQL, I am unable to understand their discussion.

Comment: See this question and answers, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1483732/set-nocount-on-usage. 

@gbn, beat me to it :)

Comment: @Pearl: I've updated that question (it's mine!)

Answer (score 0):

When SET NOCOUNT is ON, the count (indicating the number of rows affected by a Transact-SQL statement) is not returned. When SET NOCOUNT is OFF, the count is returned.

So if you do an UPDATE query (for example) the query will not return the affected rows.

for more information check out => http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259204(v=sql.80).aspx

Comment: The article you referenced simply uses misleading terminology, and frankly is wrong.  `SET NOCOUNT ON` will cause it not to *display a message indicating the number of rows returned*.  It will *not* affect the number of rows returned.  See http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/12/02/sql-server-effect-of-set-no-count-on-rowcount/