# Code not being executed, program jumps out of the loop and waits for another command

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to return 'search not found' when nothing is found in the database, but the program just jumps out the loop

I tried checking for `0` or `''`, but realized that the database returns `NoneType`. I'm checking for `None` now, but the code still does not get executed.

```py
def search():
    def searchmenu():
        print('')
        ans=str(input('Make another [s]earch or return to the [m]ain menu: '))
        ans=ans.lower()
        if ans=='s':
            Inventory.search()
        elif ans=='m':
            menu=MainMenu()
            menu.menuops()   
        else:
            print('invalid menu option')
            searchmenu()

        mydb = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost", user="root", password="", database="pharmd")
        cursor = mydb.cursor()
        query=str(input("Search: "))
        if query != "":
            cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM drugs WHERE name LIKE "%'+query+'%"')
            results=cursor.fetchall()
            if results != None:
                for data in results:
                    print('found!')
                    print(data)
                    searchmenu()
            else:
                print('No results found')
        else:
            print('Please enter a valid search!')
            print('')
            Inventory.search()
```

Comment: Why do you have `search` inside `searchmenu`, is that a typo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `cursor.fetchall()` doesn't return None but an empty tuple `()`.

You can check `cursor.rowcount` for empty result according to [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16561405/10415695) for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16561362/python-how-to-check-if-a-result-set-is-empty).