# Python MySQL results are missing some rows

Tags: python, mysql

I am learning python and trying to use it to create a PDF report based on the results of a query from MySQL database. This is the part of coding I am having trouble with

```py
qry = "SELECT <irrelevant>" 

cursor.execute(qry)
result = cursor.fetchone()
if result is not None:
    result = cursor.fetchall()
    numrows = cursor.rowcount
      return result, numrows
```

This should have yielded 3 results, as shown in the screenshot when the SQL query was run directly on the database as shown in screenshot 1.
[image]

However, when the python script is run it only retrieves two rows as shown below.
[image]

Interestingly, the cursor.rowcount returns 3 although only two records are shown.
I would love to know what I am doing wrong. Thank you.

Comment: You call `result = cursor.fetchone()` giving you the first row and then you call `result = cursor.fetchall()` which fetches the remaining two. Why select a single result first?

Comment: I was following a guide, which suggested to check if the result set is empty before proceeding as otherwise it will generate an error. I was under the impression that fetchall() would retrieve all results rather than the point from which fetchone(). 
I am using the MySQLdb module in Python.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16561362/how-to-check-if-a-result-set-is-empty

Comment: The question you link to is about 1. sqlite peculiarities in 2. the case of side-effect queries (without `RETURNING`). Such queries don't have results to return, and the dbapi2 leaves the behaviour ill-defined, as a result some drivers don't just default to an empty record set, but *no record set*. This is not an issue for a `SELECT` query, they always return a record set (possibly empty).

Comment: Furthermore as one of the answers notes, mysqldb specifically extends dbapi2 by having `execute` directly return the number of affected rows (do note that this is absolutely not portable, psycopg2 returns the cursor object instead).

Answer (score 0):

You fetch one result, which you do not use, with

```
result = cursor.fetchone()
```

you then fetch and use the other rows

```
if result is not None:             
   result = cursor.fetchall()          
   numrows = cursor.rowcount          
      return result, numrows
```

but the first row has been discarded
you could modify to

```
qry = "SELECT <irrelevant>" 

cursor.execute(qry)
result = cursor.fetchall()
if result is not None:
    numrows = cursor.rowcount
      return result, numrows
```

or to preserve your line

```
qry = "SELECT <irrelevant>" 

cursor.execute(qry)
result = cursor.fetchone()
if result is not None:
    result += cursor.fetchall()
    numrows = cursor.rowcount
      return result, numrows
```

Comment: Or just `cursor.fetchall()` to start with, the first fetch seems entirely unnecessary since you're fetching the results anyway, if there are any.

Comment: Thank you @Masklinn for guiding me. You were absolutely correct.