# Unable to connect pyODBC with SQL Server 2008 Express R2

Tags: python, sql-server, sql-server-2008, windows-xp, pyodbc

I am using following code to connect with SQL 2008 R2:

```
cnxnStoneedge = pyodbc.connect("DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=127.0.0.1;DATABASE=myDB;UID=admin;PWD=admin")
```

Which gives error:

```
Error: ('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]SQL Server does not exist or access denied. (17) (SQLDriverConnect)')
      args = ('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNE...t exist or access denied. (17) (SQLDriverConnect)')
      with_traceback = <built-in method with_traceback of Error object>
```

I am not sure whether SQL connecting via named Pipes or TCP, I did enable IP Address. Attaching Screen Shot
[image]

Comment: Does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7753830/mssql2008-pyodbc-previous-sql-was-not-a-query

Comment: No it does not. I am just making connection, rather than executing an SP

Comment: Yes but my initial problem was actually the connection, despite my error message. More often than not, it's the driver that's the root cause not the programming.

Comment: I am getting error on the line I put above. Yes I know it's about driver but I am not being able to figure out how SQL Server is trying to connect

Comment: have you installed the "Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Tool-kit" portfolio? The ENTIRE thing (including MSSQL Administrator)? because it looks to me like you're using the native windows SQL Driver which won't work. You need to connect (name) to it via `DRIVER={SQL Server Native Client 10.0}`

Comment: Your screenshot shows that you are running SQL Server Express Edition, so try using this clause in your connection string: `Server=(local)\SQLEXPRESS;` (instead of `SERVER=127.0.0.1;`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following test code works for me to connect Python 2.7.5 with SQL Server 2008 R2 Express Edition:

```python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import pyodbc

connStr = (
    r'Driver={SQL Server};' +
    r'Server=(local)\SQLEXPRESS;' +
    r'Database=myDb;' +
    r'Trusted_Connection=Yes;'
    )

db = pyodbc.connect(connStr)

cursor1 = db.execute('SELECT [word] FROM [vocabulary] WHERE [ID]=5')

while 1:
    row = cursor1.fetchone()
    if not row:
        break
    print row.word
cursor1.close()
db.close()
```

and the following connection string also works for me because my \SQLEXPRESS instance is listening on port 52865:

```python
connStr = (
    r'Driver={SQL Server};' +
    r'Server=127.0.0.1,52865;' +
    r'Database=myDb;' +
    r'Trusted_Connection=Yes;'
    )
```