# connect with sql server 2008 r2 using pyodbc, SQL Server does not exist or access denied

Tags: python, sql-server-2008-r2, pyodbc

I am not able to connect with MS SQL server 2008 R2 by using pyodbc from anaconda environment. Here is the code which I am executing :

```
import pyodbc
conn=pyodbc.connect("Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};"
                    "Server=server_name;"
                    "Database=db_name;"
                    "Trusted_Connection=yes;")
```

It gives me following error:

```
OperationalError: ('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [53].
```

I tried Driver={SQL Server}, and getting the following error:

```
OperationalError: ('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]SQL Server does not exist or access denied. (17)
```

I can connect to the server and db manually.
I have referred [Unable to connect pyODBC with SQL Server 2008 Express R2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21215128/unable-to-connect-pyodbc-with-sql-server-2008-express-r2)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try:`pyodbc.drivers()` and try other drivers.

Check here for additionnal information: [Connecting to SQL Server from Windows](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Connecting-to-SQL-Server-from-Windows)
or download {ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server}: [Driver Files - Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/windows/system-requirements-installation-and-driver-files?view=sql-server-2017)

Your code looks fine. Hard to tell from here.