# Getting error : No results. Previous SQL was not a query. during execution of UPDATE query

Tags: python, sql, sql-server-2008, twisted

I know same question has been posted and [Answer on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14979756/2419644). I tried but it is not working with **Update Query**.

```
seenQuery = ("UPDATE ChatHistorys SET isRead=1 WHERE isRead=0 AND senderId=5 AND receiverId=1")
q = dbpool.runQuery(seenQuery, ())
```

During the execution of the above query, I'm getting `No results.  Previous SQL was not a query.`

When I tried with "SELECT" and "INSERT" query, it works perfectly.

```
query = ("SET NOCOUNT ON;\nINSERT into ChatHistorys (senderId, receiverId,isRead) values (1, 4, 0)")
d = dbpool.runQuery(query, ())
```

The above code for "**INSERT**" query, which works fine for me. Then what is the issue with "**UPDATE**" Query.
Any one can help me with this ?

Comment: Are you sure there is some data with senderId=5.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai yeah data is available, and even when I run same query in sql, it affects 3 rows.