# Error "Previous SQL was not a query" in Python?

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, pyodbc

I am trying to call a stored procedure in Python but it keeps giving me the following error. The  procedure is written in SQL Server 2008 and I am using PyODBC to call the method and pass parameters to it.

```
import pyodbc
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER='+serveripaddr+';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+userid+';PWD='+password+'')
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
cursor.execute("{call p_GetTransactionsStats('KENYA', '41')}")
rows = cursor.fetchall()
```

The last line results in the following exception:

```
ProgrammingError: No results.  Previous SQL was not a query.
```

What could be the problem here?

Comment: Which error is thrown as you have two commented out?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MSSQL2008 - Pyodbc - Previous SQL was not a query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7753830/mssql2008-pyodbc-previous-sql-was-not-a-query)

Answer (score 34):

Here's what happens. The stored procedure contains several steps. When it is executed from the SQL Server Management studio, it is easy to see how each step results in a separate message such as `"(3 row(s) affected)"`, and only the very last step produces the response.

Apparently, when invoked via `pyodbc` cursor, each of those separate steps produces a separate `resultset`, where all the resultsets, but the very last one, contain no data that could be read via `fetchall()`.

Hence, one option to solve the problem is to iterate over these resultsets using `nextset()` until you find one which does produce the result, e.g.:

```
while cursor.nextset():   # NB: This always skips the first resultset
    try:
        results = cursor.fetchall()
        break
    except pyodbc.ProgrammingError:
        continue
```

A nicer option is, as mentioned in a different answer, to use the `SET NOCOUNT ON;` directive, which seems to prevent all of the intermediate, empty `(# rows affected)` resultsets. The directive can be simply prepended to the proc invocation, for example:

```
cursor.execute("set nocount on; exec MyStoredProc ?", some_parameter)
results = cursor.fetchall()
```

Comment: Calling cursor.nextset() worked for me when a sproc was actively setting nocount to off, so setting it beforehand didn't work.

Comment: I couldn't get `SET NOCOUNT ON` to work. while loop solved my problem, thank you so much.

Answer (score 5):

Can you add     SET NOCOUNT ON to you SP and try 
if you can not modify SP, first execute this statement xand then call SP

Comment: :- I tried it and it worked fine on the server but does not work from python.

Comment: @jessica - The error definitely looks like a missing `SET NOCOUNT ON;` *in the stored procedure itself*. Did you actually verify that `SET NOCOUNT ON;` is the first executable statement in the stored procedure?

Answer (score 2):

For future Googlers: I was getting this error and my stored procedure wasn't actually even inserting the data in the database table I wanted when run from pyodbc.  My problem was that I didn't close the cursor and commit after executing. Make sure you do

```
cursor.close()
connection.commit()
```

after running cursor.execute() if you're doing more than just SELECTs

Answer (score 0):

For stored procedures, you don't need .fetchall(). I had a similar issue and taking away that tag cleared it up.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered same issue.
Remember to use 'SET NOCOUNT ON' in your stored proc.
Also, check there is no 'print' statement in your stored proc.

Answer (score 0):

I got the error: "ProgrammingError: No results.  Previous SQL was not a query." on some SQL with an openquery (not a Stored Procedure). I added the "SET NOCOUNT ON" just before my openquery and cleared the error.

SQL Server
OPENQUERY to Oracle
Python pyodbc