# Launch SQL stored procedures from python with sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sqlalchemy

I can successfully connect to SQL Server Management Studio from my jupyter notebook with this script:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pyodbc 
import csv
import time
import urllib

params = urllib.parse.quote_plus('''DRIVER={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};
                                    SERVER=SV;
                                    DATABASE=DB;
                                    TRUSTED_CONNECTION=YES;''')

engine = create_engine("mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect=%s" % params)
```

I managed to execute some SQL scripts like this:

```
engine.execute("delete from table_name_X")
```

However, I can't execute stored procedures. I tried the following scripts from what I've seen in [stored procedures with sqlAlchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3563738/stored-procedures-with-sqlalchemy). These following scripts have an output like "sqlalchemy.engine.result.ResultProxy at 0x173ed18e470", but the procedure wasn't executed in reality (nothing happened):

```
# test 1
engine.execute('stored_procedure_name')
# test 2
from sqlalchemy import func
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)()
session.execute(func.upper('stored_procedure_name'))
```

Could you please give me the correct way to execute stored procedures?

Comment: The thread you linked has a lot of information that seems useful to you. Specifically, that `func` is limited. But also other comments that you should read as well. How do you know the stored procedure "was executed but nothing really happened?" This is not possible, to be honest. Either the stored procedure did not execute on the server, or it executed. Have you tried simply doing `session.execute('your_stored_proc')`? Are you including the schema? Does your proc require parameters?

Comment: check this information ...in the part Calling Stored Procedures  - > https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/connections.html

Comment: Indeed, I read and tried to adapt all the comments. I said that the stored procedure was executed but nothing happened as the python output looks like it was working whereas when I check in my sql tables, I see that the procedure didn't work

Comment: in your example you use delete ....if you try with a select....work?

Comment: Doesn't work with a select. I just put this example to show that I succeeded to execute some sql script with the engine. Thanks for your help, I'am checking your link

Comment: in your engine try add parameter case_sensitive....   create_engine(..., case_sensitive=False)

Comment: I tried to add case_sensitive=False in create_engine but it didn't change something :/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204209/discussion-between-giovanisalazar-and-ewdlam).

Comment: Just for clarity of definitions, SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) is a *Client User Interface* for the SQL Server Database. And as such you never connect to it. You are connecting to SQL Server (which is the SQL Server Database Engine).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved my problem with the following function :

```
def execute_stored_procedure(engine, procedure_name):
    res = {}
    connection = engine.raw_connection()
    try:
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute("EXEC "+procedure_name)
        cursor.close()
        connection.commit()
        res['status'] = 'OK'
    except Exception as e:
        res['status'] = 'ERROR'
        res['error'] = e
    finally:
        connection.close() 
    return res
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you can call a stored procedure using pyodbc is :

```
cursor.execute("{CALL usp_StoreProcedure}")
```

I found a solutions in reference to this link . https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Calling-Stored-Procedures

Here a example :

```
import pyodbc
import urllib
import sqlalchemy as sa


params = urllib.parse.quote_plus("DRIVER={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};"
                                 "SERVER=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;"
                                 "DATABASE=DB;"
                                 "UID=user;"
                                 "PWD=pass")

engine = sa.create_engine("mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={}".format(params))

connection = engine.raw_connection()
try:
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute("{CALL stored_procedure_name}")
    result = cursor.fetchall()
    print(result)
    connection.commit()
finally:
    connection.close()
```

Comment: I have this error when I try your solution :
<ipython-input-326-acd489de44b9> in <module>
      3     cursor = connection.cursor()
      4     cursor.execute("{CALL procedure_name}")
----> 5     result = cursor.fetchall()
      6     print(result)
      7     connection.commit()

ProgrammingError: No results.  Previous SQL was not a query.

Comment: @Ewdlam check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41302866/error-previous-sql-was-not-a-query-in-python