# Running a system Stored Procedure of SQL Server using python pyodbc

Tags: python, sql-server

I am trying to run a system SP (which is a pre-built) using python `pyodbc`. In fact I am trying to see the dependencies on a table using `sp_depends '<Object name>';`

I am using the below code snippet.

```
df_f=[]
l_table = ['table_1','table_2','table_3']
try:
  for l in l_table:
    sql = """EXEC sp_depends '{0}';""".format(l)
    while cur.nextset():
        cur.execute(sql)
        c = cur.fetchall()
        df_l= pd.DataFrame.from_records(c, columns = [desc[0] for desc in cur.description])
        df_l['Referenced_Object'] = l
        df_f.append(df_l)
        break
except pyodbc.Error as err:
  s = str(err)
  print(s)
finally:
  cur.close()
  cnxn.close()
```

The above code is not running. It is not throwing error but not appending anything in `df_f`.

If I run the above SP separately, I am getting the below error:

```
ProgrammingError: No results.  Previous SQL was not a query.
```

I have taken help from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41302866/error-previous-sql-was-not-a-query-in-python) SO thread.

I am not able to `SET NOCOUNT ON` in this SP as this is a built-in and therefore I am not able to get the desired information in dataframe.

Any clue on this?

Comment: FYI, `sp_depends` is deprecated anyway, so perhaps you should be looking at an alternative system object. See the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-depends-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) for more information. If you use the objects that are replacing it, the whole problem of `SET NOCOUNT` not being set to `ON` goes away.

Comment: Also, I **strongly** suggest you learn to parametrise; the above is wide open to SQL Injection attacks.

Comment: @Larnu:Didn't quite understand the `parametrise` part. I know about `sys.dm_sql_referencing_entities` but this doesn't give the result as `sp_depends` give. I mean I need the output exactly same as `sp_depends`.

Comment: I suggest a read of [Why do we always prefer using parameters in SQL statements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505808/why-do-we-always-prefer-using-parameters-in-sql-statements) If you aren't aware of parametrisation, you ***need*** to go back to the basic of SQL and interacting with it your from programming layer; it is a fundamental part of using an RDBMS.

Comment: @Larnu: I am quite aware of parametrization in SQL server and I dont see this as a compelling need to implement in the OP. Can you please share your thoughts on any alternative approach of the OP?

Comment: *"I dont see this as a compelling need to implement in the OP."* Because injection is **dangerous**. It's the 2020's and it is *still* one of the most prolific and fatal security flaws out there. There is a reason companies are named, shamed and fined millions when they are foolish enough to suffer a breach due to things like SQL injection; because it's simple to parametrise queries and there have been enough incidents over the last 30 years that people have *no* excuse to follow such bad programming standards because they "didn't know better".

Comment: Point taken. Will surely do the same when finally put the same on production. Thanks for sensitizing.

Comment: Any alternative approach on this?

Comment: As I mentioned, you'll want to use the new DMV's linked in the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, `sp_depends` has been deprecated; it should not be used. As per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-depends-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) you should be using [`sys.dm_sql_referencing_entities`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-sql-referencing-entities-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) and [`sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-sql-referenced-entities-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) instead.

You can get similar results to the `sp_depends` with the following queries. You would need to replace the variables with parameters from your programming language (**not** inject them):

```sql
SELECT CONCAT(re.referenced_schema_name,'.', re.referenced_entity_name) AS [name],
       o.type_desc AS [Type],
       CASE re.is_updated WHEN 0 THEN 'no' WHEN 1 THEN 'yes' END AS updated,
       CASE re.is_selected WHEN 0 THEN 'no' WHEN 1 THEN 'yes' END AS selected,
       re.referenced_minor_name AS [column]
FROM sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities(QUOTENAME(@SchemaName) + N'.' + QUOTENAME(@ObjectName) ,'OBJECT') re
     JOIN sys.objects o ON re.referenced_id = o.object_id;

SELECT DISTINCT
       CONCAT(re.referencing_schema_name,'.', re.referencing_entity_name) AS [name],
       o.type_desc AS [Type]
FROM sys.dm_sql_referencing_entities(QUOTENAME(@SchemaName) + N'.' + QUOTENAME(@ObjectName) ,'OBJECT') re
     JOIN sys.objects o ON re.referencing_id = o.object_id;
```