# In Sql Server What is Noncount?

Tags: sql-server-2008

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SET NOCOUNT ON usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1483732/set-nocount-on-usage)

What is "NOCOUNT ON" in sql server, what it is do, where we can use it.

Comment: [SET NOCOUNT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189837.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

It used to set ON/OFF the message that shows the count of the number of rows affected.[image]