# NHibernate INSERT TO SQL Calculated field SET NOCOUNT

Tags: sql, nhibernate, sql-function

I need to surpress messages output from a SQL function.  As in `1 row affected`.  I can't use `SET NOCOUNT` as it's invalid in a function.

Anyone know a way to do this?

Thanks.

**EDIT**

I was trying to limit the background information in an attemp to boil the problem down to it's essence.  But I'll expand.  I'm using MSSQL2005 and NHibernate to insert a record in to a SQL table.  On the table I have a computed column that runs the function which is reporting back `1 row affected`.

I didn't really want to edit the NHibernate part of the process but it may be unavoidable.

Comment: What kind of database are you using?  Sql Server, MySql, Oracle, etc?

Comment: Does it not work, or are you not able to SET NOCOUNT from the code calling the function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A function that returns "(1 row affected)" will be part of a bigger query in a batch. It makes no sense to have `SET NOCOUNT ON` *in* the function

You need to do this:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
SELECT * FROM MyUDFTVF();
```

Note a stored procedure is simply a wrapper for this

```
CREATE PROC Whatever
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SELECT * FROM MyUDFTVF();
GO
```

`SET NOCOUNT ON` is normally [needed to stop triggers etc breaking client code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1483732/set-nocount-on-usage): why do you need it here?

Comment: Leading on from this answer I have decided to change from using NHibernate native to just putting a SP in place for the inserting the new record.  This should solve the issue.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The `nocount` setting is not available in functions.

Stored procedures allow you to set `nocount`.  So converting the function to a stored procedure would solve the problem.

Otherwise, the calling code will have to set `nocount`.  That shouldn't be hard, but might be tedious if the function is used in many places.

P.S. If you post the reason why suppressing the count messages is required, perhaps we can offer some more solutions.