# MSSQL 2005 - JDBC4 and subqueries

Tags: java, sql-server-2005, t-sql, jdbc, database-connection

I tried a query which

- A) fills var table
- B) gets the var table data as helpful to select next data

> ```
> CREATE PROCEDURE  Test
> AS
> BEGIN
> DECLARE @A TABLE
> (
> id INT NOT NULL,
> name VARCHAR(50)
>
> );
>
> INSERT @A SELECT id,name FROM table1 WHERE id>10
>
> DECLARE @B TABLE
> (
>
>   address VARCHAR(255),
>   city VARCHAR(128)
>
> );
>
> INSERT @b SELECT address,city FROM table2
> WHERE id IN(SELECT id FROM @A) 
> END;
> ```

... so, as a result, I have two select statements in my procedure :S The thing is... All procedures which contain just one select statement behave fine with JDBC4 but here something is wrong because when procedure contains two select statement it returns nothing :( So my question can two select statement cause the problem with jdbc4? A if it does how to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding `SET NOCOUNT ON` (edit: once at the top of the procedure body) to the stored procedure. The result of this is sent back and may be confusing JDBC 4: this is quite common...

See [SET NOCOUNT ON usage](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1483732/27535) for more

```
CREATE PROCEDURE  Test
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON; -- here

DECLARE @A TABLE
...
```

Comment: Oh, I am not pretty sure... where should I add it? to block the first select statement?

Comment: Thank you it works. But it makes query more slow to get result?