# Make my stored procedure more efficient

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have already created a stored procedure for Select Query and it is working Fine.
But I need some thing more efficient to make my SP Query.
Have you any suggestion for that.

```
Create Procedure usp_SelectUserProfile
    @UserId int
As
Begin
     Select <column name> from DB where UserId = @UserId
End
```

Thnx

Comment: Do you actually have a problem with speed? There's not much you can do to improve that query. If UserId is the PK then it should be a simple index seek.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only thing i can imagine here is:

```
Create Procedure usp_SelectUserProfile
    @UserId int
As
Begin
     SET NOCOUNT ON;
     Select <column name> from DB where UserId = @UserId
End
```

Suppresses sending the amount of affected rows to client, on small procedures with many calls can save you up to 17% of call time

Comment: Suppresses sending the amount of affected rows to client, on small procedures with many calls it can save you up to 17% of call time

Comment: 17% is oddly specific - I'd be interested to read any reference you have for that

Comment: @Blorgbeard - read it in the book, now I'll try to find a reference

Comment: Thanks! Don't take too much trouble if you can't find it, just an idle curiosity :)

Comment: @Blorgbeard - actually - found it! Citation: Best Practice
With every returned record set, SQL Server will, by default, also send a message stating the number of
rows affected or returned. Not only is this a nuisance, but I have found in my informal testing that it
can slow a query by up to 17 percent depending on the query’s complexity.
Therefore, get into the habit of beginning every stored procedure with the following code:
CREATE PROC MyProc
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON; Citation ends (Paul Nielsen, Mike White, Uttam Parui - Microsoft Sql Server Bible, p.622 ISBN 978-0-470-25704-3

Comment: @OlegDok: See my question here for lots more: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1483732/set-nocount-on-usage

Comment: @gbn - great post, thanks, I knew only about problems with linq2sql and editing the rows directly from ssms when NOCOUNT is globally OFF with startup option

Answer (score 0):

you can use     `SET NOCOUNT ON`

```
Create Procedure usp_SelectUserProfile
@UserId int
As
Begin
 SET NOCOUNT ON
 Select <column name> from DB where UserId = @UserId
End
```

read this for more details http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189837.aspx

Answer (score 0):

1. If UserID is not the Primary key, then create a new index on `(UserID) INCLUDE (<column name>)`
2. Qualify all object references with schema `Select <column name> from dbo.MyTable where UserId = @UserId`. Also use this on the stored procedure too. Without this, you'll prevent plan re-use
3. Ensure datatype and length of column `UserId` and `@UserId` are identical to avoid datatype precedence and implicit conversions
4. Add SET NOCOUNT ON as mentioned on other answers: see [SET NOCOUNT ON usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1483732/set-nocount-on-usage)