# How to get affected records using ExecuteNonQuery when multiple insert statements are used in C# for SQL

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I am running an insert query from c# using:

```
string affectedRows = myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery().ToString();
```

However the query that I am running does two things. It first inserts stuff into a temp table, and then inserts stuff into the real-table.

Eg:

```
declare @t table (a int)
insert into @t 
values(1)

insert into MyTable
select * from @t
```

Since it does two inserts, my affectedrows will be 2.
The question is how to i get either the last result of the insert, or perhaps an array/list of results?

Dividing by 2 won't help me, as there maybe multiple queries, etc and it won't always be 2. the above is just an example. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just change the SET NOCOUNT statement to view the lines that really matter:

example:

```
set nocount off

declare @t table (a int)
insert into @t 
values(1)

set nocount on

declare @MyTable table (b int)

insert into @MyTable
select * from @t
```

See the Messages tab in SSMS.

Comment: +1, but the OP wants the affected records of the last statement, not the first. So first `nocount on` and latter `nocount off`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1483732/set-nocount-on-usage