# Simple results formatting from SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I have been doing SQL for a while and I've always been satisfied to use the `Results to Grid` found in SSMS.

Now I have a series of queries that I am running and I would like to have some very simple formatting of the results. Currently neither the `Results to Grid` nor the `Results to Text` do quite what I would like to do.

A few things I would like to do so it is easier for me to read is

1. Remove the text that says '# row(s) affected' (found in the `Results to Text`)
2. Make the columns not so wide in the column aligned Output Format (part of the problem is that the Maximum Number of Characters does not appear to go below 30 - is this my data that forces this?)

If I cannot format the output (even to a text file) what other options do I have ?

I spent some time looking at SQL Server -> PHP -> HTML as well as SQL Server -> Reporting Services -> MS Report Builder but quite frankly it seems like overkill to put a few spacers and pretty up the headings a bit.

I feel like I am missing something here ...   I would rather not go through the hassle of all that installation of PHP and what not just to be able to look at my data a *little* bit prettier.

Comment: Related (not duplicate): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1483732/set-nocount-on-usage

Comment: I just found this excellent link on how to write directly to HTML from SQL Server.  It is a very fast/simple technique that allows you to nicely & simply format reports http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/robert_davis/2010/06/15/Building-HTML-Emails-With-SQL-Server-and-XML/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Remove the text that says '# row(s) affected' (found in the Results to Text)

Put this `SET NOCOUNT ON` at the top of your sql

> Make the columns not so wide in the column aligned Output Format (part
>   of the problem is that the Maximum Number of Characters does not
>   appear to go below 30 - is this my data that forces this?)

Yes its the size of the field that does this. You can cast it `cast(field as varchar(20)`to make it smaller if you know you won't lose data.

Answer (score 2):

It all depends on what you want to do with the formatted results.

For quickly reading / formatting a result that isn't great when viewed directly in Management Studio, I use `Results to Grid`, select all with headers (by right-clicking on the upper-left corner of the grid), and copy/paste into **Excel**.  From there it's easy to do basic tinkering with column widths and formatting.  The biggest downside for me is dates are never quite right out-of-the-box, but it's always a quick fix.

Excel also makes a good interim stop for basic formatting when I'm pasting query results into an email.

It might be overkill in some cases, but I suspect much less so than using PHP -> HTML or Reporting Services -> MS Report Builder.