# Visual Basic: Can't read record/data from recordset.

Tags: sql, vba, asp-classic, recordset

Here is my Code:

```
Dim CompanyName, _
    CompanyDomain, _
    CompanyEmail, _
    CompanySupportPhone

Call GetEmailList

Sub GetEmailList
    dim sql
    dim companydata

    sql = ""
    sql = sql & " DECLARE @CompanyName VARCHAR(100);"
    sql = sql & " DECLARE @CompanyDomain VARCHAR(100);"
    sql = sql & " DECLARE @CompanyActivityEmail VARCHAR(100);"
    sql = sql & " DECLARE @CompanySupportPhone VARCHAR(100);"

    sql = sql & " SELECT"
        sql = sql & " @CompanyName = CASE WHEN Setting = 'CompanyName'"
        sql = sql & " THEN StringValue ELSE @CompanyName END,"
        sql = sql & " @CompanyDomain = CASE WHEN Setting = 'CompanyDomain'"
        sql = sql & " THEN StringValue ELSE @CompanyDomain END,"
        sql = sql & " @CompanyActivityEmail = CASE WHEN Setting = 'CompanyActivityEmail'"
        sql = sql & " THEN StringValue ELSE @CompanyActivityEmail END,"
        sql = sql & " @CompanySupportPhone = CASE WHEN Setting = 'CompanySupportPhone'"
        sql = sql & " THEN StringValue ELSE @CompanySupportPhone END"
    sql = sql & " FROM ClientSettings"
    sql = sql & " WHERE Setting in ('CompanyDomain','CompanyActivityEmail','CompanySupportPhone','CompanyName')"

    sql = sql & " SELECT ISNULL(@CompanyName, '') AS CompanyName, ISNULL(@CompanyDomain, '') AS CompanyDomain, ISNULL(@CompanyActivityEmail, '') AS CompanyEmail, ISNULL(@CompanySupportPhone, '') AS CompanySupportPhone"
    set companydata =  getRecordset(sql)

    CompanyName = companydata("CompanyName") ' LINE 80
    CompanyDomain = companydata("CompanyDomain")
    CompanyEmail = companydata("CompanyEmail")
        CompanySupportPhone = companydata("CompanySupportPhone")

        companydata.Close
        Set companydata = Nothing
End Sub
```

This throws an error:

> Line 80
>
> Item cannot be found in the collection corresponding to the requested
>   name or ordinal.

I marked line 80 above.  I run this exact same SQL in SQL Server Manager and it returns results:

```
CompanyName CompanyDomain   CompanyEmail    CompanySupportPhone
MyCompanyName   http://localhost    MyCompanyName@email.com 801-555-1212
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong here?

GetRecordSet correctly loads and processes the database call, this function works in 1,000 other places.  I'm sure the problem isn't there.

Comment: Please choose a more descriptive title for your question. "I'm having trouble with Visual Basic" ... who isn't?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add

```
sql = sql & " SET NOCOUNT ON;"
```

as the first SQL statement.

[SET NOCOUNT ON usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1483732/set-nocount-on-usage)

Comment: That was it, thank you.  Any idea why not having that breaks it?

Comment: Updated the comment with a link to detailed description about this.

Comment: @amit_g:  Yeah that link points to a lot of text.  So for clarity the answer is simply this:  At times ADODB gets itself confused and believes the single "count of rows" returned be SQL server is to be treated as a recordset.  Most of the time we don't need this value so "SET NOCOUNT ON" prevents SQL Server from sending this phantom recordset and avoids ADODB become confused at times.

Comment: That explained it perfectly, I'll be adding this a lot more from now on.