# Using Dapper.net to call stored procedure, always return -1 back

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, dapper

here's my stored procedure.  when I test it, always get correct result back.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[AddSmoothieIngredients]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @Query NVARCHAR(4000) ,
    @SmoothieId INT ,
    @CreatedDate DATETIME ,
    @Status INT ,
    @UserId INT
AS 
    BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
        SET NOCOUNT ON;

        BEGIN TRY
            BEGIN TRAN

            IF @SmoothieId > 0 
                BEGIN
                    DELETE  FROM dbo.SmoothieIngredients
                    WHERE   SmoothieId = @SmoothieId;

                    EXECUTE (@Query);
                END
            ELSE 
                BEGIN

                    IF @UserId = 0 
                        SET @UserId = NULL;

                    INSERT  INTO dbo.Smoothie
                            ( Name, CreatedDate, Status, UserId )
                    VALUES  ( N'', @CreatedDate, @Status, @UserId );

                    SET @SmoothieId = SCOPE_IDENTITY();

                    SET @Query = REPLACE(@Query, 'sId', @SmoothieId);
                    EXECUTE (@Query);

                END 


            COMMIT TRAN

            RETURN @SmoothieId

        END TRY

        BEGIN CATCH
            ROLLBACK
        END CATCH

    END
```

However When I call this stored procedure using dapper.net, always return -1 back.

```
        using (var conn = OpenConnection())
        {
            var parameter = new { Query = query, SmoothieId = smoothieId, CreatedDate = createdDate, Status = status, UserId = userId  };
            return conn.Execute("AddSmoothieIngredients", parameter, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
        }
```

Probably, dapper.net cannot pick up the return value from the stored procedure.  but I really dont know how to fix it. please help.

Answer (score 22):

So the reason that Execute() returns -1 is because your sproc has `SET NOCOUNT ON;` which "suppresses the "xx rows affected" message after any DML" according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1547539/3255130). Whether you want to disable that or not is another question also discussed in that link.

I just came across the same problem so I thought I'd throw in my 2 cents.

Comment: Never knew this! +1

Comment: Thank you! I was pulling my hair out after creating an INSERT stored procedure based on a SELECT one and didn't remove the SET NOCOUNT ON; line.

Comment: Bless your soul, I've been searching this for over 20 minutes :)

Answer (score 15):

Found the solution, here's the sample code I found online. and it works.

```
var p = new DynamicParameters();
p.Add("@a", 11);
p.Add("@b", dbType: DbType.Int32, direction: ParameterDirection.Output);
p.Add("@c", dbType: DbType.Int32, direction: ParameterDirection.ReturnValue);

cnn.Execute("spMagicProc", p, commandType: commandType.StoredProcedure); 

int b = p.Get<int>("@b");
int c = p.Get<int>("@c");
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like Dapper.net uses the SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery for the Execute method. This returns the number of rows affected, not the value of the return statement. What you're looking for is `Query`

```
return connection.Query<int>("AddSmoothieIngredients", parameter, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure).First();
```

Although I don't think that will capture the return statement either, in which case you'll need to alter the stored procedure to return a results set.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[AddSmoothieIngredients]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @Query NVARCHAR(4000) ,
    @SmoothieId INT ,
    @CreatedDate DATETIME ,
    @Status INT ,
    @UserId INT
AS 
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    BEGIN TRY
        BEGIN TRAN

        IF @SmoothieId > 0 
            BEGIN
                DELETE  FROM dbo.SmoothieIngredients
                WHERE   SmoothieId = @SmoothieId;

                EXECUTE (@Query);
            END
        ELSE 
            BEGIN

                IF @UserId = 0 
                    SET @UserId = NULL;

                INSERT  INTO dbo.Smoothie
                        ( Name, CreatedDate, Status, UserId )
                VALUES  ( N'', @CreatedDate, @Status, @UserId );

                SET @SmoothieId = SCOPE_IDENTITY();

                SET @Query = REPLACE(@Query, 'sId', @SmoothieId);
                EXECUTE (@Query);

            END 


        COMMIT TRAN

        SELECT @SmoothieId
        RETURN
    END TRY

    BEGIN CATCH
        ROLLBACK
    END CATCH

END
```

Or you could use another DB access method.

Comment: thanks.  but you still have to use execute, I found another sample online, and it works.

Answer (score 2):

Recently I had to change an existing procedure to additionally return a value, and I had been using an anonymous type to pass the parameters. In this context, the really nice thing is that `DynamicParameters` supports an anonymous type as an input parameter, which makes this change easy to implement.

I had the following:

```
cnn.Execute("spMagicProc", new { a = 11, x = 13, y = 14, z = "something" },
  commandType: commandType.StoredProcedure);
```

I was able change that to:

```
var p = new DynamicParameters(new { a = 11, x = 13, y = 14, z = "something" });
p.Add("@rval", dbType: DbType.Int32, direction: ParameterDirection.ReturnValue);

cnn.Execute("spMagicProc", p, commandType: commandType.StoredProcedure);

int rval = p.Get<int>("@rval");
```