# .NET ODBC + SQL Server: How to throw error up to calling application from stored proc?

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, odbc

I am calling a SQL Server stored procedure from a C# .NET application using the System.Data.Odbc library. 
I want to be able to throw errors up to the calling application as I have been able to in the past with other drivers using raiserror or throw:

`raiserror('message',18,0)`

but the errors apparently aren't causing the SP to abandon execution and pass the error upwards.

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Thanks

Comment: Are you consuming data in a DataReader or DataAdaptor.Fill(DataTable)?

Comment: Neither. Sorry should have mentioned I am calling procs with OdbcCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've discovered this is a known issue with ODBC - for errors to be caught and OdbcExceptions to be thrown, you must SET NOCOUNT ON.

Comment: This relates to my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1483732/set-nocount-on-usage