# SQL set noCount on in all query

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I have a stored proecdure like below:

```
@userInput int

as
declare isSuperUser int
declare IDs table(
recordID int
);

set isSuper = select isSuper from [User]
if(@isSuper = 1)
Begin
    insert into recordID select * from TableA
End
else
Begin
    insert into recordID select * from TableB
End

select * from recordID
```

And I would like to add "set noCount on" on every query, so the question is: is the performance in store procedureA equivalent to store procedureB?

store procedureA :

```
@userInput int

as
declare isSuperUser int
declare IDs table(
recordID int
);
set noCount on
set isSuper = select isSuper from [User]
if(@isSuper = 1)
Begin
    insert into recordID select * from TableA
End
else
Begin
    insert into recordID select * from TableB
End

select * from recordID
set noCount off
```

store procedureB:

```
@userInput int

as
declare isSuperUser int
declare IDs table(
recordID int
);
set noCount on
set isSuper = select isSuper from [User]
set noCount off
if(@isSuper = 1)
Begin
    set noCount on
    insert into recordID select * from TableA
    set noCount off
End
else
Begin
    set noCount on
    insert into recordID select * from TableB
    set noCount off
End
set noCount on
select * from recordID
set noCount off
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SET NOCOUNT ON usage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1483732/set-nocount-on-usage)

Answer (score 1):

`SET NOCOUNT ON` prevents the sending of `DONE_IN_PROC` messages to the client for each statement in a stored procedure. For stored procedures that contain several statements that do not return much actual data, or for procedures that contain Transact-SQL loops, setting `SET NOCOUNT` to ON can provide a significant performance boost, because network traffic is greatly reduced.

[TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189837%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)

While storedProcedure is executing , there is no point of sending data back to client, setting `noCount On` increases performance as it reduces network traffic .
In your Store Procedure B you are switching NoCount on to off which increases network traffic.