# SQLServerException: A result set was generated for update

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I'm trying to insert a new record into an MS SQL database, and I'm getting an exception I've never seen before. When I call `executeUpdate` the following exception is thrown:

`com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: A result set was generated for update.`

This is the Java code that produces the error:

```
// addComment method adds a new comment for a given requestId
public CommentBean addComment(CommentBean comment) {
    PreparedStatement stmt = null;
    INative nat = null;
    Connection conn = null;

    try {
        nat = dbConn.retrieveNative();
        conn = (Connection)nat.getNative("java.sql.Connection");
        stmt = conn.prepareStatement(ADD_COMMENT);
        stmt.setInt(1, comment.getRequestId());
        stmt.setString(2, comment.getComment());
        stmt.setString(3, new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").format(comment.getDateCreated()));
        stmt.setString(4, comment.getCreatedBy());
        comment.setCommentId(stmt.executeUpdate()); // exception
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        System.err.println("ProjectRegistration::SQLDAO - addComment");
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (stmt != null) stmt.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {}
    }

    return comment;
}// end addComment
```

Where ADD_COMMENT is defined as a String:

`private static final String ADD_COMMENT = "INSERT INTO RequestComments OUTPUT INSERTED.commentId VALUES(?,?,?,?)";`

For the sake of being thorough, the table is defined as:

```
CREATE TABLE RequestComments (
    commentId int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
    requestId int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Requests(requestId),
    comment varchar(400),
    dateCreated date,
    createdBy varchar(12)
);
```

I don't think I'm doing anything terribly complicated here, but I can't think of why I'm getting this exception. I have a method in the same class which does the exact same type of insertion (literally the same query with a different table name and number of values), and it has no issues. Does anyone have any ideas on how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This instruction `stmt.executeUpdate()` is not returning the commentId, it returns a [ResultSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html) which you could then get the commentId from. Something like this,

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(); // Not update, you're returning a ResultSet.
if (rs.next()) {
  comment.setCommentId(rs.getInt(1));
}
```

Comment: I have another query in the same class which is of the form `String NEW_REQUEST = "INSERT INTO Requests OUTPUT INSERTED.requestId VALUES(?,...`. I retrieve the id with `stmt.executeUpdate()`. Is there any reason for an inconsistency like this? Or a way to predict it?

Comment: Ah well, your suggestion works. I'm guessing SQL Server is okay with returning the result via `executeUpdate` only in certain cases. It's an annoying inconsistency, but my code works now.

Answer (score 9):

This particular error can also be caused by an INSERT-trigger, which has a SELECT-statement as a part of the trigger code.

To test whether this is the case, you can try:

- using `executeQuery()`, instead of `executeUpdate()` - and display the result.
- executing the insert in tool like MySQL Workbench, SQL Server Management Studio, or whatever flavour of database design tools are available for your DBMS, to see whether a result is returned.

Related: [sql server error "A result set was generated for update"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24214706/sql-server-error-a-result-set-was-generated-for-update)

I'm hoping this may help others looking at the same error message, as it did for me. My solution was to live with a call to `executeQuery()`, although it only handles an underlying issue, instead of fixing it.

Comment: I use mssql. "using executeQuery(), instead of executeUpdate() - and display the result."
result is saved me

Answer (score 4):

you are using OUTPUT in your insert query i.e you will get a resultset after your query executes and to hold that you need an object of class ResultSet to hold that data

Answer (score 2):

SqlServer : When SET NOCOUNT is ON, the count is not returned. When SET NOCOUNT is OFF, the count is returned.

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectDB,user,pwd);
String sql = " set nocount off;INSERT INTO test (name) values (1)";   

PreparedStatement prepareStatement = conn.prepareStatement(sql,Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
System.out.println(prepareStatement.executeUpdate());

ResultSet generatedKeys = prepareStatement.getGeneratedKeys();
if(generatedKeys.next()){
    System.out.println(generatedKeys.getString(1));
}
```

Related: 
[set-nocount-on-usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1483732/set-nocount-on-usage)

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similar problem where after a while an insert on a autonumber table would give a "A result set was generated for update." at random. I use connection pooling and somehow the driver can get into a state where executeUpdate in combination with Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS doesn't work anymore. I found out that in this state an executeQuery does the trick, but in the initial state executeQuery does not work. This lead me to the following workaround:

```
PreparedStatement psInsert = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO XYZ (A,B,C) VALUES(?,?,?)", Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
ResultSet rs = null;
try {
    psInsert.setString(1, "A");
    psInsert.setString(2, "B");
    psInsert.setString(3, "C");
    Savepoint savePoint = connection.setSavepoint();
    try {
        psInsert.executeUpdate();
        rs = psInsert.getGeneratedKeys();
    } catch (SQLServerException sqe)
    {
        if (!sqe.getMessage().equals("A result set was generated for update."))
            throw sqe;
        connection.rollback(savePoint);
        rs = psInsert.executeQuery();
    }
    rs.next();
    idField = rs.getInt(1);
} finally {
    if(rs != null)
        rs.close();
    psInsert.close();
}
```