# Is there a better alternative to SqlDataAdapter

Tags: sql, ado.net

When I create a stored procedure, I use

```
  SET NOCOUNT ON
```

as this speeds up execution time. From this question, [SET NOCOUNT ON usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1483732/set-nocount-on-usage), using `SqlDataAdapter` relies upon the rows affected value to be returned. I was wondering if you work with an alternative class that works well for:-

- IF EXISTS to avoid duplicates (no rows affected message)
- Note: use with caution `WHERE NOT EXISTS` (less rows then expected filter out trivial updates (eg no data actually changes)
- Do any table access before (such as logging) Hide complexity or denormlisation
- etc

Answer (score 1):

You could use SqlDataReader.  It is a lower level interface that allows you to process each row individually and only extract data you need.  It does buffering of results internally.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

If you want a simple ORM that hides complexity look at Dapper: https://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) Is SqlDataAdapter used often nowadays?

Comment: If you use ASP.NET WebForms, datatables are common and SqlDataAdapter as designed for them, but other than that not really.