# Understanding ExecuteNonQuery's return value

Tags: c#, mysql, stored-procedures

First, just to be clear, I recognize that `ExecuteNonQuery` should only be used for `UPDATE, INSERT, or DELETE` statements, and that for all other types of statements, such as SELECT, the return value is -1.

My question is, why does the following stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `ExampleProc`(IN Name varchar(60), OUT ID bigint(20), OUT SP varchar(255))
BEGIN
    SELECT id, sp INTO ID, SP FROM users WHERE username = Name;
END
```

When executed using `ExecuteNonQuery`:

```
using (var conn = new MySqlConnection("Secret"))
{
    conn.Open();
    using (var cmd = new MySqlCommand("ExampleProc", conn) { CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure })
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Name", request.Name).MySqlDbType = MySqlDbType.VarChar;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("ID", MySqlDbType.Int64).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("SP", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
        var returnVal = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Yield a `0 in returnVal` when a row with Name is not found, and a `1` if it is found? Based on all the documentation I have read, since the stored procedure contains a `single SELECT statement`, I should be seeing `-1` being returned no matter what. Instead, it's returning the number of rows affected/found, which doesn't make sense according to the documentation.

Lastly, I've also tried using just `"SELECT *" instead of "SELECT id, sp INTO ID, SP"`. That seems to always return `0`. Still not the `-1` that I am expecting.

Comment: Check the link 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ms188774.aspx
for Select statement try setting `Set RowCount <Number>` and test. Also please note behavior you have mentioned is specific to Sql Server, may behave different for different databases

Answer (score 1):

Let's understand the working of the `ExecuteNonQuery` API in the ADO.Net, as you have understood from the documentation that it shall provide the number of Rows impacted as part of `DML` query and -1 for the `Select` query.

However the internal working is such that in case of `Sql Server`, default setting is `Set NoCount Off` helps in writing to the `TDS protocol`, the number of modified rows and same is read by the Ado.Net APIs, thus the correct result, this is the result of native binary integration of `ado.net` with `Sql Server`. more details at the following links:

[Ado.Net TDS Protocol](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e85ad5e5-a30e-4ccf-aeab-0774185e7576/set-nocount-on-and-sqlcommandexecutenonquery-and-sqldataadapterupdate?forum=adodotnetdataproviders)

[SET NOCOUNT ON usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1483732/set-nocount-on-usage)

When it comes to other database, like `MySql`, `Oracle`, there's no guarantee of the same behavior, as their integration is not at same level as `Sql Server`. This is the main reason for discrepancy, posted in the question, to make it consistent across the database, you may want to rely of a `Output Parameter` to automatically fill the value internally in the procedure, since every database has mechanism to figure out the number of rows updated

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It seems strange that there would be a discrepancy, especially since the same behavior is described right in the MySQL docs: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-net/html/M_MySql_Data_MySqlClient_MySqlCommand_ExecuteNonQuery.htm. Additionally, as a test, instead of a stored procedure, I set up MySqlCommand with "SELECT * FROM users" and that returns -1, so it appears there is something wrong with how the stored procedure works. Any tips?

Comment: @Eaton need to get little deeper in the finer details, though the link posted by you provide the same details, but I am certain there's some aspect or setting like `NoCountON` of the `Sql Server` for `My Sql`, which need to be explored to understand the deviation in the behavior

Comment: I did some research and could not find anything. NOCOUNT doesn't appear to be used in any form in MySQL.

Comment: `NOCOUNT` is `Sql Server` specific, there has to be another option, main point remains the result to be correct need understanding of the implementation as done in `Sql Server`, which only data connector team can explain. I remember `Oracle` doesn't work correctly with `ExecuteNonQuery`, as `ODP.Net` don't have option like  `Sql Server`

Comment: This is looking like a bug to me. I tried using ExecuteReader and its returned MySqlDataReader's "HasRows" property is true, even though it should be false since I pass in a bogus username. Interestingly, using the returned MySqlDataReader's "Read" method returns false the first time. At this point I think I will just use Read to determine whether the SELECT in my stored procedure finds anything, as these other properties and return values appear to be unreliable.

Comment: May or may not be a bug, since it is not mandatory for the provider to implement everything  provided by abstract class like `DbDataReader`, which will be the base class for the `MySqlDataReader`, its important that you go as per documentation and if it is not inline then a bug. Not necessary for everyone to follow Microsoft documentation