# An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll Additional information: Input string was not in a correct format

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to insert a form data into database but there is some problem with the code that I'm unable to identify it. The Error is:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>   Additional information: Input string was not in a correct format.

Winform code:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Media;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MobShopManagSys
{
    public partial class Product_AddForm : Form
    {
        ProductsDB db = new ProductsDB();
        public Product_AddForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void SaveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (IsValidated()) //Proceed if required data is entered
            {
                db.InsertProductInDB(NameTextBox.Text, Convert.ToInt32(CategoryComboBox.SelectedValue), ModelTextBox.Text, SeriesComboBox.Text, Convert.ToInt32(SIMSlotsComboBox.Text), CarrierTypeComboBox.Text, GetReleaseDate(), Convert.ToInt32(RAMTextBox.Text), RAMMemUnitComboBox.Text, Convert.ToInt32(SecondryMemTextBox.Text), SecondMemUnitComboBox.Text, Convert.ToInt32(ExpandableTextBox.Text), ExpandableMemUnitComboBox.Text, OSVersionComboBox.Text, ProcessorComboBox.Text, ScreenSizeTextBox.Text, ScreenSizeTypeComboBox.Text, Convert.ToInt32(BatteryTextBox.Text), BatteryTypeComboBox.Text, CommentsTextBox.Text, Convert.ToInt32(SupplierComboBox.SelectedValue), float.Parse(PriceTextBox.Text), PriceUnitComboBox.Text, Convert.ToInt32(QuantityTextBox.Text), SaveProductPhoto());
                MessageBox.Show("New Record is added successfully!", "Record Added", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }
        }

        private void CloseButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }
        private void AddSupplierButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Suppliers_AddForm AddNewSupplierFrm = new Suppliers_AddForm();
            AddNewSupplierFrm.ShowDialog();
            //Reload Data into control
            LoadFormControlsData();

        }
        private void ResetButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            NameTextBox.Clear();
            CategoryComboBox.Text = " ";
            ModelTextBox.Clear();
            SeriesComboBox.Text = null;
            CarrierTypeComboBox.Text = null;
            SIMSlotsComboBox.Text = null;
            ReleaseDateTimePicker.CustomFormat = " ";

            RAMTextBox.Clear();
            RAMMemUnitComboBox.Text = null;
            SecondryMemTextBox.Clear();
            SecondMemUnitComboBox.Text = null;
            ExpandableTextBox.Clear();
            ExpandableMemUnitComboBox.Text = null;

            OSVersionComboBox.Text = null;
            ProcessorComboBox.Text = null;
            ScreenSizeTextBox.Clear();
            ScreenSizeTypeComboBox.Text = null;
            BatteryTextBox.Clear();
            BatteryTypeComboBox.Text = null;

            CommentsTextBox.Clear();

            SupplierComboBox.Text = null;
            PriceTextBox.Clear();
            PriceUnitComboBox.Text = null;
            QuantityTextBox.Clear();

            SystemSounds.Beep.Play();
            NameTextBox.Focus();
        }
        private void Product_AddForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            LoadFormControlsData();
        }

        private void LoadFormControlsData()
        {
            CategoryComboBox.DataSource = db.LoadCategoryComboBox();
            CategoryComboBox.DisplayMember = "CategoryName";
            CategoryComboBox.ValueMember = "CategoryID";
            CategoryComboBox.SelectedIndex = -1;


            SeriesComboBox.DataSource = db.LoadSeriesComboBox();
            SeriesComboBox.DisplayMember = "Series";

            SupplierComboBox.DataSource = db.LoadSupplierComboBox();
            SupplierComboBox.DisplayMember = "Name";
            SupplierComboBox.ValueMember = "SupplierID";
            SupplierComboBox.SelectedIndex = -1;
        }
        private void AddNewCategoryButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Categories_AddForm AddCategoryFrm = new Categories_AddForm();
            AddCategoryFrm.ShowDialog();

            LoadFormControlsData();
        }
        private void ProductImagePictureBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
            ofd.Title = "Select the Image";
            ofd.Filter = "Image File (*.png;*.jpg;*.bmp;*.gif)|*.png;*.jpg;*.bmp;*.gif";

            if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                ProductImagePictureBox.Image = new Bitmap(ofd.FileName);
            }
        }
        private byte[] SaveProductPhoto()
        {
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            ProductImagePictureBox.Image.Save(ms, ProductImagePictureBox.Image.RawFormat);
            return ms.GetBuffer();
        }
    private bool IsValidated()  //Validation Method Defination
        {
            if (NameTextBox.Text.Trim() == "")
            {
                ValidationMessage(NameTextBox, "Name is required!");
                return false;
            }
            if (CategoryComboBox.Text.Trim() == "")
            {
                ValidationMessage(CategoryComboBox, "Please select the Category/Brand!");
                return false;
            }
            if (ModelTextBox.Text.Trim() == "")
            {
                ValidationMessage(ModelTextBox, "Model is required!");
                return false;
            }
            if (RAMTextBox.Text.Trim() == "")
            {
                ValidationMessage(RAMTextBox, "RAM memory required!");
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                float outRAM;
                if(!float.TryParse(RAMTextBox.Text, out outRAM))
                {
                    ValidationMessage(RAMTextBox, "RAM field only contain numbers!");
                    return false;
                }
            }
            if (RAMMemUnitComboBox.Text.Trim() == "")
            {
                ValidationMessage(RAMMemUnitComboBox, "Please select a Memory Unit!");
                return false;
            }

            if (SecondryMemTextBox.Text.Trim() == "")
            {
                ValidationMessage(SecondryMemTextBox, "Secondry memory field is required!");
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                float outSecMem;
                if (!float.TryParse(RAMTextBox.Text, out outSecMem))
                {
                    ValidationMessage(RAMTextBox, "Secondry memory field only contain numbers!");
                    return false;
                }
            }
            if (SecondMemUnitComboBox.Text.Trim() == "")
            {
                ValidationMessage(SecondMemUnitComboBox, "Please select a Memory Unit!");
                return false;
            }
            if (ExpandableTextBox.Text != "")
            {
                int outexpmem;
                if (!int.TryParse(ExpandableTextBox.Text, out outexpmem))
                {
                    ValidationMessage(ExpandableTextBox, "Expandable memory can only numbers!");
                    return false;
                }
              if (ExpandableMemUnitComboBox.Text.Trim() == "")
                {
                    ValidationMessage(ExpandableMemUnitComboBox, "Please select a Memory Unit!");
                    return false;
                }
            }
            if (OSVersionComboBox.Text.Trim() == "")
            {
                ValidationMessage(OSVersionComboBox, "OS Version selection is required!");
                return false;
            }
            if (BatteryTextBox.Text.Trim() == "")
            {
                ValidationMessage(BatteryTextBox, "Battery Capacity required!");
                return false;
            }
            if (BatteryTypeComboBox.Text.Trim() == "")
            {
                ValidationMessage(BatteryTypeComboBox, "Please select a Battery Capacity Unit!");
                return false;
            }
            if(PriceTextBox.Text != "" )
            {
                float outexpmem;
                if (!float.TryParse(PriceTextBox.Text, out outexpmem))
                {
                    ValidationMessage(PriceTextBox, "Purchase Price only numbers!");
                    return false;
                }
              if (PriceUnitComboBox.Text.Trim() == "")
                {
                    ValidationMessage(PriceUnitComboBox, "Please select Currency Unit!");
                    return false;
                }
            }

            if (QuantityTextBox.Text.Trim() == "")
            {
                ValidationMessage(QuantityTextBox, "Quantity of Product is required!");
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                int outQuantity;
                if (!int.TryParse(QuantityTextBox.Text, out outQuantity))
                {
                    ValidationMessage(QuantityTextBox, "Quantity can only in numbers!");
                    return false;
                }
             }
            return true;
            }

        private void ValidationMessage(Control ctrl, string ValidationMsg) //Validation Message Def.
        {
            ctrl.BackColor = Color.LightPink;
            MessageBox.Show(ValidationMsg, "Validation Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            ctrl.Focus();
        }

        private void ctrl_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) //Back change color to white
        {
            Control ctrl = (Control)sender;
            ctrl.BackColor = Color.White;
        }
        private void ClearCommentsButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CommentsTextBox.Clear();
            CommentsTextBox.Focus();
        }
        //Date Time Picker   <Start>
        private void ReleaseDateTimePicker_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ReleaseDateTimePicker.CustomFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy";
        }

        private void ReleaseDateTimePicker_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if(e.KeyCode==Keys.Back || e.KeyCode == Keys.Delete)
            {
                ReleaseDateTimePicker.CustomFormat = " ";
            }
        }
        private DateTime? GetReleaseDate()
        {
            if (ReleaseDateTimePicker.Text.Trim() == string.Empty)
            {
                return (DateTime?)null;
            }
            else
                return ReleaseDateTimePicker.Value.Date;
        }


    }  //Date Time Picker   <End>

}
```

Error in this line of code:

```
db.InsertProductInDB(NameTextBox.Text, Convert.ToInt32(CategoryComboBox.SelectedValue), ModelTextBox.Text, SeriesComboBox.Text, Convert.ToInt32(SIMSlotsComboBox.Text), CarrierTypeComboBox.Text, GetReleaseDate(), Convert.ToInt32(RAMTextBox.Text), RAMMemUnitComboBox.Text, Convert.ToInt32(SecondryMemTextBox.Text), SecondMemUnitComboBox.Text, Convert.ToInt32(ExpandableTextBox.Text), ExpandableMemUnitComboBox.Text, OSVersionComboBox.Text, ProcessorComboBox.Text, ScreenSizeTextBox.Text, ScreenSizeTypeComboBox.Text, Convert.ToInt32(BatteryTextBox.Text), BatteryTypeComboBox.Text, CommentsTextBox.Text, Convert.ToInt32(SupplierComboBox.SelectedValue), float.Parse(PriceTextBox.Text), PriceUnitComboBox.Text, Convert.ToInt32(QuantityTextBox.Text), SaveProductPhoto());
```

#### Database Class Code

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MobShopManagSys
{
    class ProductsDB
    {
        string connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString;

        //Add Product Form
        public void InsertProductInDB(string Name, int CategoryID, string Model, string Series, int SIMSlots, string CarrierType, DateTime? ReleaseDate, int RAM, string RAMMemUnit, int SecondryMem, string SecondMemUnit, int Expandable, string ExpandableMemUnit, string OSVersion, string Processor, string ScreenSize, string ScreenSizeType, int Battery, string BatteryType, string Comments, int SupplierID, float Price, string PriceUnit, int UnitsInStock, byte[] SaveProductPhoto)
        {
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spProducts_InsertProduct", conn))
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    //Parameters
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", Name);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CategoryID", CategoryID);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Model", Model);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Series", Series);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SIMSlots", SIMSlots);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CarrierType", CarrierType);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ReleaseDate", ReleaseDate);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RAM", RAM);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RAMMemUnit", RAMMemUnit);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SecondryMem", SecondryMem);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SecondMemUnit", SecondMemUnit);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Expandable", Expandable);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ExpandableMemUnit", ExpandableMemUnit);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OSVersion", OSVersion);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Processor", Processor);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ScreenSize", ScreenSize);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ScreenSizeType", ScreenSizeType);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Battery", Battery);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BatteryType", BatteryType);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Comments", Comments);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SupplierID", SupplierID);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PurchasePrice", Price);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PurchasePriceUnit", PriceUnit);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UnitsInStock", UnitsInStock);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductPhoto", SaveProductPhoto);
                    //Connection
                    conn.Open();
                    //Execution
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
        }
        public DataTable LoadCategoryComboBox()
        {
            DataTable categoryComboboxValues = new DataTable();

            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spProducts_GetAllCategories", conn))
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                    conn.Open();
                    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    categoryComboboxValues.Load(reader);
                }
            }
            return categoryComboboxValues;
        }
        public DataTable LoadSeriesComboBox()
        {
            DataTable seriesComboBoxValues = new DataTable();

            using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
            {
                using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spProducts_GetAllSeries", conn))
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                    conn.Open();
                    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    seriesComboBoxValues.Load(reader);
                }
            }
            return seriesComboBoxValues;
        }
        public DataTable LoadSupplierComboBox()
        {
            DataTable supplierComboBoxValues = new DataTable();

            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spProducts_GetAllSuppliers", conn))
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                    conn.Open();
                    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    supplierComboBoxValues.Load(reader);
                }
            }
            return supplierComboBoxValues;
        }
    }
}
```

#### Stored procedure

```
ALTER Procedure [dbo].[spProducts_InsertProduct]
 @Name          nvarchar(50)
,@CategoryID    int
,@Model         nvarchar(50)
,@Series        nvarchar(50)
,@SIMSlots      int
,@CarrierType   nvarchar(20)
,@ReleaseDate   DateTime = null
,@RAM           int
,@RAMMemUnit    nvarchar(20)
,@SecondryMem   int
,@SecondMemUnit nvarchar(20)
,@Expandable    int
,@ExpandableMemUnit nvarchar(20)
,@OSVersion     nvarchar(50)
,@Processor     nvarchar(50)
,@ScreenSize    nvarchar(50)
,@ScreenSizeType nvarchar(20)
,@Battery       int
,@BatteryType   nvarchar(20)
,@Comments      nvarchar(MAX)
,@SupplierID    int
,@Price         float
,@PriceUnit     nvarchar(20)
,@UnitsInStock  int
,@ProductPhoto  IMAGE
As
Begin

INSERT INTO tblProducts(Name,CategoryID,Model,Series,SIMSlots,CarrierType,ReleaseDate,RAM,RAMMemUnit,SecondryMem,SecondMemUnit,Expandable,ExpandableMemUnit,OSVersion,Processor,ScreenSize,ScreenSizeType,Battery,BatteryType,Comments,SupplierID,Price,PriceUnit, UnitsInStock, Product_Photo)
VALUES(@Name,@CategoryID,@Model,@Series,@SIMSlots,@CarrierType,@ReleaseDate,@RAM,@RAMMemUnit,@SecondryMem,@SecondMemUnit,@Expandable,@ExpandableMemUnit,@OSVersion,@Processor,@ScreenSize,@ScreenSizeType,@Battery,@BatteryType,@Comments,@SupplierID,@Price,@PriceUnit,@UnitsInStock, @ProductPhoto)

End
```

Help me please I'm stuck here from two days.
Thanks!

Comment: a stored procedure must always have "set nocount on" as first statement

Comment: `CategoryComboBox.SelectedValue` seems to be in a wrong format to be converted to `int`. How does the string it look like? is it a `string` at all? does it have a comma or a dot in it?

Comment: @GuidoG I just gave the main idea of stored procedure.!

Comment: @MahiCh So is there more code in the stored proc ? If so then please show the entire code

Comment: @MongZhu it is an integer value to be save in product form retrieved from Categories table explained in DB class.

Comment: when the error occurs and the debugger is on line "db.InsertProductInDB(...)" then have you checked each input value for this method to see if they all can be converted ?

Comment: @GuidoG it is complete code.

Comment: @MahiCh then you are missing the "set nocount on" code in the stored proc. Not that it will fix your current problem but best put it there to avoid further problems

Comment: @GuidoG The error code is "Input string is not in correct format", So I don't think there may be any conversion relevant error. However, I'll re-check it.

Comment: It seems like its just one of your input values for method InsertProductInDB that can not be converted. Check in debug that all values can be converted, note that null also cannot be converted

Comment: @MahiCh can you please clarify "set nocount on". Because all other procedures working accurately like this coded.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1483732/set-nocount-on-usage

Comment: @MahiCh But about your real problem, please check in debug that all input values for the method InsertProductInDB that need to be converted, also can be converted. Some are converted from a textedit.text, which can be empty or contain values that cannot be converted to int.

Comment: @GuidoG there is no debug error.

Comment: @GuidoG can you please clarify how to check that each value is converted, If there is some value that is not converted then debugger should warn, and give error that one or more values are not converted.

Comment: if there is no debug error then where does the error text from your question comes from ?

Comment: @GuidoG On runtime when save button is clicked.

Comment: You wrote that the error occurs on "db.InsertProductInDB()" but you dont know that for sure then. Please run this from visual studio in debugmode and look where the error occurs

Comment: Can you edit the question and add the sample responses when you are getting exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This validation works if the text box is not empty

```
if (ExpandableTextBox.Text != "")
{
    int outexpmem;
    if (!int.TryParse(ExpandableTextBox.Text, out outexpmem))
    {
        ValidationMessage(ExpandableTextBox, "Expandable memory can only numbers!");
        return false;
    }
  if (ExpandableMemUnitComboBox.Text.Trim() == "")
    {
        ValidationMessage(ExpandableMemUnitComboBox, "Please select a Memory Unit!");
        return false;
    }
}
```

But the line you're getting the error is trying to this `Convert.ToInt32(ExpandableTextBox.Text)` on every case.

If the ExpandableTextBox text is empty, this line will throw the error like you receive

```
db.InsertProductInDB(NameTextBox.Text, Convert.ToInt32(CategoryComboBox.SelectedValue), ModelTextBox.Text, SeriesComboBox.Text, Convert.ToInt32(SIMSlotsComboBox.Text), CarrierTypeComboBox.Text, GetReleaseDate(), Convert.ToInt32(RAMTextBox.Text), RAMMemUnitComboBox.Text, Convert.ToInt32(SecondryMemTextBox.Text), SecondMemUnitComboBox.Text, Convert.ToInt32(ExpandableTextBox.Text), ExpandableMemUnitComboBox.Text, OSVersionComboBox.Text, ProcessorComboBox.Text, ScreenSizeTextBox.Text, ScreenSizeTypeComboBox.Text, Convert.ToInt32(BatteryTextBox.Text), BatteryTypeComboBox.Text, CommentsTextBox.Text, Convert.ToInt32(SupplierComboBox.SelectedValue), float.Parse(PriceTextBox.Text), PriceUnitComboBox.Text, Convert.ToInt32(QuantityTextBox.Text), SaveProductPhoto());
```

You can try something like this for optional fields `Convert.ToInt32(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ExpandableTextBox.Text)?ExpandableTextBox.Text :"0")`

Comment: Of-course, if someone enter some text then it check that weather expandabletextbox value is int and its memory unit is selected. So this is not an error.

Comment: But user must have to know about the error/miss entered content.

Comment: Look at error, error is that when insert data in db, input string is not in correct format. No validation(definition) error. I skipped this part of code but same error occurs. "Not an answer at all"

Comment: if you want to see same error message try this `Convert.ToInt32(string.Empty)`

Comment: Then what for `Convert.ToInt32(SupplierComboBox.SelectedValue)`?

Comment: Will this work.? `Convert.ToInt32(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(SupplierComboBox.Text) ? SupplierComboBox.SelectedValue : "0")`

Comment: SupplierComboBox.SelectedValue default value is null. you can use direct Convert.ToInt32(SupplierComboBox.SelectedValue)

Comment: Means null is convertable.?

Comment: you can make performance optimization after mandatory steps to be taken

Comment: Thanks a lot bro.